# File not getting saved in specified location in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

Eventhough i specify a different location the file gets saved in mydocuments. How to resolve this issue. Pls share your ideas if any.Here is the code.

```
          if (externalButton.Checked == true)
            {
               // int i = 1;
                saveFileDialog.Title = "Save the Proofer Report";
                saveFileDialog.Filter = "Document Files (*.doc)|*.doc|Document Files (*.docx)|*.docx";
                saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
                saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "MyDocuments";
                saveFileDialog.FileName = "Proofer Report -- " +  Path.GetFileName((string)fileName) + ".doc";
                //i.tostring()
                saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".doc"; 


                saveFileDialog.ShowHelp = true;
                // saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
                var thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(param => { saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); }));
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
                fname = saveFileDialog.FileName;
```

Comment: Am using a different thread as i am getting "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made” error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are showing dialog assynchronously on new thread and code after starting the thread executes *before* dialog is shown (most of the time).

Either wait for thread completion or move saving to that thread after dialog is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Why You Are Showing `saveFileDialog` in different thread?
if you show save dialog in diffrent thread `fname = saveFileDialog.FileName;` is always return null.dont use separate thread.or Call this event after thread start

```
saveFileDialog1.FileOk += new CancelEventHandler(saveFileDialog1_FileOk);
 void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string fname = null;
            fname = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
```

**Edited**

Example

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _SaveFileDialog.FileOk += new CancelEventHandler(_SaveFileDialog_FileOk);
        }
        string filename = null;
        SaveFileDialog _SaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        private void savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _SaveFileDialog.Title = "Save the Proofer Report";
            _SaveFileDialog.Filter = "Document Files (*.doc)|*.doc|Document Files (*.docx)|*.docx";
            _SaveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
            _SaveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "MyDocuments";
            _SaveFileDialog.FileName = "Proofer Report -- .doc";
            _SaveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".doc";
            _SaveFileDialog.ShowHelp = true;
            var thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(param => { _SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); }));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }
        void _SaveFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            filename = _SaveFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Am using a different thread as i am getting "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made”
error

Comment: make save dialog in ui thread show it in your thread with `  thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);`

Comment: i dint understand how to save dialog in ui thread..hw do i do that?

Comment: @user1665707 See my Edit Example,i write a simple one

Comment: The file is not getting saved anywhere

Comment: i get object ref not set to instance of an object at this line   
var thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(param => { _SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); }));

Comment: i think This error says you don't init save dialog i think you have missing some thing

Comment: i added invoke and its working fine now.
 Invoke((Action)(() => { saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); }));